How to link checkbox-elements in a hierarchy-like unordered list?
I want my checkboxes to be linked: when I click on the level 2 checkbocks, I want all checkbockses be affected from starting from level 3. So far, I could come up only with this (I clicked on the level 2 checkbox): example
My template lookes like this:

<div id="checkbox-list" class="scrollable-list">
    <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="_"><label for="_">Level 1</label>
            <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="_"><label for="_">Level
                        2</label>
                    <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71" id="71"><label
                                for="_">Level 3</label>
                            <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:0" id="71:0"><label
                                        for="71:0">Level 4</label></li>
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:1" id="71:1"><label
                                        for="71:1">Level 4</label></li>
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:2" id="71:2"><label
                                        for="71:2">Level 4</label></li>
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:3" id="71:3"><label
                                        for="71:3">Level 4</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94" id="94"><label
                                for="_">Level 3</label>
                            <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94:0" id="94:0"><label
                                        for="94:0">Level 4</label></li>
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94:1" id="94:1"><label
                                        for="94:1">Level 4</label></li>
                                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94:2" id="94:2"><label
                                        for="94:2">Level 4</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="_"><label for="_">Level 2</label>
            <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_"
                        id="_"><label for="_">Level 3</label>
                    <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_"
                                id="_"><label for="_">Level 4</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

I add event listeners to every checkbox I create with my script. My current JS code lookes like this:
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var flag = this.checked
            var nestedCheckboxes = this.parentElement.querySelector('.checkbox-inner-element').querySelectorAll('ul li input[type="checkbox"]');
            nestedCheckboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
                checkbox.checked = flag;
                checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            });
        })

I think the problem could be in that I have both <li> and <ul> tags on the same level, but I couldn't come up with the solution yet.

What is checkbox? Wondering if something like querySelectorAll("#"+currentCheckboxID + " input[type=checkbox]") might work to get all descendant checkboxes.

do you want to check all descendants of a specific checkbox? in that case the image you provided is not doing that

Also, I don't think the ids on your checkboxes are valid

@ITgoldman yeah, that’s the result I’m getting - it’s not what I want to

@mykaf I believe, ids are not the primary concern at the moment, it’s what I test now

I would use query selectors to find all of the descendant checkboxes. This solution uses the input id, which I don't believe are allowed to start with a number.


document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(checkbox =>
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const activeCB = e.target;
    const flag = activeCB.checked;
    const descendants = activeCB.closest("li").querySelectorAll(`input[type=checkbox]`);
    
    descendants.forEach(d => d.checked = flag);
  })

)
<div id="checkbox-list" class="scrollable-list">
  <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
    <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="L1a"><label for="_">Level 1</label>
      <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="L2a"><label for="_">Level
            2</label>
          <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
            <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71" id="L3a"><label for="_">Level 3</label>
              <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:0" id="L4a"><label for="71:0">Level 4</label></li>
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:1" id="L4b"><label for="71:1">Level 4</label></li>
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:2" id="L4c"><label for="71:2">Level 4</label></li>
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="71:3" id="L4d"><label for="71:3">Level 4</label></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94" id="L3b"><label for="_">Level 3</label>
              <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94:0" id="L4e"><label for="94:0">Level 4</label></li>
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94:1" id="L4f"><label for="94:1">Level 4</label></li>
                <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="94:2" id="L4g"><label for="94:2">Level 4</label></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="L1b"><label for="_">Level 2</label>
      <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
        <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="L2b"><label for="_">Level 3</label>
          <ul class="checkbox-outer-element">
            <li class="checkbox-inner-element"><input type="checkbox" value="_" id="L3c"><label for="_">Level 4</label></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




It didn't worked for me. The weird thing is that document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { console.log(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")) }) returns an empty node list -_-

The code works in CodePen with my current template... I make sure your code runs on the DOMContentLoaded, but it doesn't work in my ptoject anyway. What the problem can be?

Your code finally worked. It turned out there were some problems with the Liveserver :)) I hosted a Python server and everything worked perfectly! Also I changed doctument.eventlistenter() to 'readystatechange' and it helped too. I'm not sure if it suits for the production though XD. Anyway, thank you for your help!
